# How to get data in string from database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

i am working on android client and .NET server application, in which i parse data into xml and then convert into string and then send this string to android client.now i am facing problem in getting data from SQL Server in xml format and convering it into string.here is my code..

```
 UserLogin userLogin = converter.GetObjectFromXml<UserLogin>(xml);
    String query = @"Select StdBD.First_NameEn As name from TblStudentBioData As StdBD Join TblStudentDetail As StdDet ON StdBD.Student_ID = StdDet.Student_ID
       join TblClassSchedule As ClsSch on StdDet.ClassID = ClsSch.ClassSchID
     join TblClass As Cls on ClsSch.ClassID = Cls.ClassID 
     join TblSemAssigning As SemAs on SemAs.SemAssId = ClsSch.SemAssId
     join TblAcademicYear As Acd on SemAs.AcademicYearId = Acd.AcademicYearId
     where Acd.AcademicYearId = " + userLogin.userId + "FOR XML RAW('Student'),Root('Students'),Elements";
     String outputXml = General.ExecuteSimpleSelectQuery(General.connectionString, query, "Table user");
                   Console.WriteLine("xmllll = "+outputXml);
```

and

```
   class General
   {
    public static String ServerIp = "192.168.1.2";
    public static String ServerPort = "8060";
    public static String connectionString =    NetService2.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnString.ToString();

    public static String ExecuteSimpleSelectQuery(string ConnectionString, string _Query, string DataTableName)
    {      
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_Query,conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = null;          
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name = " + reader[0].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        return "";
    }
```

Output:

[image]

by using this code i am getting data in SqlDataReader instance but not in string,so is there any way to directly get data into string or convert  SqlDataReader instance data into string,so i can use it.

i want output like this:

```
String xml = "<Students>
  <Student>
    <name>Aliya</name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <name>Fahad</name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <name>iqra</name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <name>iqra</name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <name>khurram</name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <name>Zainab</name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <name>Fatima</name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <name>Fahad</name>
  </Student>
</Students>";
```

replace this hard coded xml to the xml, getting from database.

Comment: Your question is not very clear but have you tried the .ToString() method?

Comment: [SqlDataReader.GetString()?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get your XML data in a DataTable it will give you an xml at its first position and then convert it into an string.

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);            
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(your query,conn);
    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(DataTableName);
    conn.Open();
    SDA.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    String xml =  dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    return xml;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple put your query into storedprocedure

```
 Create PROCEDURE yourprocedurename
 AS
 BEGIN
 Select StdBD.First_NameEn As name from TblStudentBioData As StdBD 
 Join TblStudentDetail As StdDet ON StdBD.Student_ID = StdDet.Student_ID
 join TblClassSchedule As ClsSch on StdDet.ClassID = ClsSch.ClassSchID
 join TblClass As Cls on ClsSch.ClassID = Cls.ClassID 
 join TblSemAssigning As SemAs on SemAs.SemAssId = ClsSch.SemAssId
 join TblAcademicYear As Acd on SemAs.AcademicYearId = Acd.AcademicYearId
 where Acd.AcademicYearId = " + userLogin.userId + "FOR XML 
 RAW('Student'),Root('Students'),Elements";
 END
```

and from coding side do something like this

```
public static String ExecuteSimpleSelectQuery(string ConnectionString, 
                                  string _Query, string DataTableName)
    {      
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("yourstoredprocedurename",conn);
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(DataTableName);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        return dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    }
```

hopefully it will give you the required output

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.Join` after you've loaded all records into a `List<string>`:

```
public static String ExecuteSimpleSelectQuery(string ConnectionString, string _Query, string DataTableName)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_Query, conn))
    {                
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add("name = " + reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
}
```

However, don't use string concatenation for your sql commands because you are vulnerable to sql-injection. So don't pass the query to the method `ExecuteSimpleSelectQuery`. Instead use sql-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will always return empty string as you return "" after every time function is called. Try change your function as:

```
public static String ExecuteSimpleSelectQuery(string ConnectionString, string _Query, string DataTableName)
    {      
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_Query,conn);
            string result;
        conn.Open();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load( cmd.ExecuteReader());


        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
        dt.WriteXml(sw);
         result = sw.ToString();
       }

        conn.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can capture your column data into a `string`.  By default, all of your data types will be considered an `object`.  Which means you'll have to:

- Use the `SqlDataReader` built in function.
- Use the `ToString()`
- Use a `(string)` or `as string` Cast.

Before I provide an example, something you should do before you attempt to work with the data, a `null` check.

```
if(reader[0] != DBNull.Value)
{
     // Do Something...
}
```

The reason, is if you perform certain manipulations on the data you'll receive an *Exception*.  Another useful thing, wouldn't be to use `[0]` but rather the `["NameOfColumn"]` as later on maintaining the code, will make the specific data easier to read and see what it does.

```
if(reader["NameOfColumn"] != DBNull.Value)
     example = reader["NameOfColumn"].ToString();

if(reader["NameOfColumn"] != DBNull.Value)
     example = (string)reader["NameOfColumn"];

example = reader["NameOfColumn"] as string;
```

Those are some primitive examples, the last one if it fails will assign a `null`.  So you'll want to anticipate that bubbling potentially in your code.  The first example, is the most common and simple.

However, if you want to avoid repeating said code.

```
public static class DataReaderExtension
{
     public static string GetStringOrNull(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal)
     {
          var value = null;
          if(!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(ordinal)
               reader.GetString(ordinal);

          return value;
     }

     public static string GetStringOrNull(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)
     {
          return reader.GetStringOrNull(reader.GetOrdinal(columnName));
     }
}
```

Those are several different approaches.  Hopefully that indeed helps you.